# How to check individual item in FlatList with checkbox in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-elements

I am creating a react native app and I used this [react native checkbox](https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/checkbox.html)  to check individual item in a FlatList. But if I check one Item, it checked all the Item in FlatList. I can't use any status in data array like [this question answer 1.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59931276/how-can-we-check-uncheck-individual-checkbox-in-flatlist-based-on-index-or-by-ke) Are there any way to do this or How to do check individual Item in a FlatList?

[image: Sample Screen 1]
[image: Sample screen 2]

**This is what I tried,**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  Alert,
  ScrollView,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';
import {CheckBox} from 'react-native-elements';

export default class Test extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      calls: [
    {id:1,  name: "Mark Doe",   date:"12 jan", time:'11:14 am', image:"https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar7.png"},
    {id:2,  name: "Clark Man",  date:"12 jul", time:'15:58 am', image:"https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar6.png"} ,
    {id:3,  name: "Jaden Boor", date:"12 aug", time:'12:45 am', image:"https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar5.png"} ,
    {id:4,  name: "Srick Tree", date:"12 feb", time:'08:32 am', image:"https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar4.png"} ,
    {id:5,  name: "John Doe",   date:"12 oct", time:'07:45 am', image:"https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar3.png"} ,
    {id:6,  name: "John Doe",   date:"12 jan", time:'09:54 am', image:"https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png"} ,
    {id:8,  name: "John Doe",   date:"12 jul", time:'11:22 am', image:"https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png"} ,
    {id:9,  name: "John Doe",   date:"12 aug", time:'13:33 am', image:"https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar4.png"} ,
    {id:10, name: "John Doe",   date:"12 oct", time:'11:58 am', image:"https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar7.png"} ,
    {id:11, name: "John Doe",   date:"12 jan", time:'09:28 am', image:"https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png"},
  ],
      checked: true,
    };
  }

  renderItem = ({item}) => {

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Image source={{ uri: item.image }} style={styles.pic} />
          <View>
            <View style={styles.nameContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.nameTxt}>{item.name}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.end}>
              <Image style={[styles.icon, {marginLeft:15, marginRight:5, width:14, height:14}]} source={{uri:"https://img.icons8.com/small/14/000000/double-tick.png"}}/>
              <Text style={styles.time}>{item.date} {item.time}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <CheckBox
            // iconRight
            title="SMS"
            checkedIcon="dot-circle-o"
            uncheckedIcon="circle-o"
            checked={this.state.checked}
            onPress={() => this.setState({checked: !this.state.checked})}
          />

        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }} >
          <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 26,
            color: '#0080ff',
            textAlign: 'center',
            marginBottom: 30,
            marginTop: 10,
          }}>
          Testing check box
        </Text>
        <FlatList 
          extraData={this.state}
          data={this.state.calls}
          keyExtractor = {(item) => {
            return item.id;
          }}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderColor: '#dcdcdc',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',

  },
  pic: {
    borderRadius: 25,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  },
  nameContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    // width: 270,
  },
  nameTxt: {
    marginLeft: 15,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: '#222',
    fontSize: 15,

  },
  mblTxt: {
    fontWeight: '200',
    color: '#777',
    fontSize: 13,
  },
  end: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  time: {
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: '#666',
    fontSize: 12,

  },
  icon:{
    height: 28,
    width: 28, 
  }
});
```

Comment: each `item` in `state.calls` should have a `checked` property, then `checked={item.checked}`

Comment: updated - and tested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

github repo: https://github.com/denistsoi/so-61772299

In `state.calls`, each item should have a `checked` property, then checkbox should have the prop `checked={item.checked}`

You'll need to change onPress to alter the calls state

```
  isChecked = (itemId) => {
    const isThere = this.state.ids.includes(itemId);
    return isThere;
  };

  toggleChecked = (itemId) => {
    const ids = [...this.state.ids, itemId];

    if (this.isChecked(itemId)) {
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        ids: this.state.ids.filter((id) => id !== itemId),
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        ids,
      });
    }
  };
```

```
<CheckBox
  // iconRight
  title="SMS"
  checkedIcon="dot-circle-o"
  uncheckedIcon="circle-o"
  checked={this.isChecked(item.id)}
  onPress={() => this.toggleChecked(item.id)}
/>
```

**component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  Alert,
  ScrollView,
  FlatList,
} from 'react-native';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      calls: [
      {id:1,  name: "Mark Doe",   date:"12 jan", time:'11:14 am', image:"https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar7.png"},
      {id:2,  name: "Clark Man",  date:"12 jul", time:'15:58 am', image:"https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar6.png"} ,
      {id:3,  name: "Jaden Boor", date:"12 aug", time:'12:45 am', image:"https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar5.png"} ,
      {id:4,  name: "Srick Tree", date:"12 feb", time:'08:32 am', image:"https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar4.png"} ,
      {id:5,  name: "John Doe",   date:"12 oct", time:'07:45 am', image:"https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar3.png"} ,
      {id:6,  name: "John Doe",   date:"12 jan", time:'09:54 am', image:"https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar2.png"} ,
      {id:8,  name: "John Doe",   date:"12 jul", time:'11:22 am', image:"https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png"} ,
      {id:9,  name: "John Doe",   date:"12 aug", time:'13:33 am', image:"https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar4.png"} ,
      {id:10, name: "John Doe",   date:"12 oct", time:'11:58 am', image:"https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar7.png"} ,
      {id:11, name: "John Doe",   date:"12 jan", time:'09:28 am', image:"https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png"},
      ],
      ids: [],
    };
  }

  isChecked = (itemId) => {
    const isThere = this.state.ids.includes(itemId);
    return isThere;
  };

  toggleChecked = (itemId) => {
    const ids = [...this.state.ids, itemId];

    if (this.isChecked(itemId)) {
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        ids: this.state.ids.filter((id) => id !== itemId),
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        ids,
      });
    }
  };

  renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.row}>
          <Image source={{ uri: item.image }} style={styles.pic} />
          <View>
            <View style={styles.nameContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.nameTxt}>{item.name}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.end}>
              <Image
                style={[
                  styles.icon,
                  { marginLeft: 15, marginRight: 5, width: 14, height: 14 },
                ]}
                source={{
                  uri: 'https://img.icons8.com/small/14/000000/double-tick.png',
                }}
              />
              <Text style={styles.time}>
                {item.date} {item.time}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <CheckBox
            // iconRight
            title="SMS"
            checkedIcon="dot-circle-o"
            uncheckedIcon="circle-o"
            checked={this.isChecked(item.id)}
            onPress={() => this.toggleChecked(item.id)}
          />
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 26,
            color: '#0080ff',
            textAlign: 'center',
            marginBottom: 30,
            marginTop: 10,
          }}
        >
          Testing check box
        </Text>
        <FlatList
          extraData={this.state}
          data={this.state.calls}
          keyExtractor={(item) => {
            return `${item.id}`;
          }}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderColor: '#dcdcdc',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  pic: {
    borderRadius: 25,
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  },
  nameContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    // width: 270,
  },
  nameTxt: {
    marginLeft: 15,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: '#222',
    fontSize: 15,
  },
  mblTxt: {
    fontWeight: '200',
    color: '#777',
    fontSize: 13,
  },
  end: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  time: {
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: '#666',
    fontSize: 12,
  },
  icon: {
    height: 28,
    width: 28,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: Is there any way to do without using any state inside my "call" array?

Comment: if you upvote i can edit this - but basically you have a value that stores the index that you're selecting

Comment: I can do upvote. The problem is I am getting values to an array using a API. There is no any status like checked property. That's why I am looking to do it in another way.

Comment: I tried your first method. But It gives me an error. "Can't find variable:state"

Comment: I tried your second method too. It only can check one item at a time. I need to check multiple items.

Comment: I’m at dinner, I’ll clean this up after.

Comment: Ok. Have a nice dinner.

Comment: Can You look into my other question too? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61790114/how-to-compare-two-array-in-react-native/61790431#61790431)